# Specify an arbitrary argument in addition to *args in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, positional-argument

For a function with multiple arguments like this:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
```

it is straightforward to define a new function as follows:

```
def g(a, *args):
    return f(a, *args)
```

here, `a` is the first argument of `f()`. What if I would like to specify the second argument of `f()`, namely:

```
def g(b, *args):
    # return f(???)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  In the case you're asking about, what do you intend the *other* arguments to `f` to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack some of the arguments from `*args`:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c


def g(b, *args):
    a,*rest = args
    return f(a, b, *rest)


print(g(1,2,3))
```

Output:

`6`

Answer (score 1):

You are just reordering the args in you last example such that `b` is the the first named args.  However, you will need to unpack `*args` to get `a` and `c` before passing them to `f`.

```
def g(b, *args):
    a, c = args
    return f(a, b, c)
```